# How do I insert a subreport into my report using VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access

Alright I have 4 subreports which all have a data source.

(Sureport | Data Source)

(subreport1 |  Query1)
(subreport2 |  Query2)
(subreport3 |  Query3)
(subreport4 |  Query4)

and so on...

When I open the report, I want to check if Query1, 2, 3 and 4 exists and based on that, I will add the right subreports to my main report.

I'm very new to access and don't really know where to start. Which is the best approach to my problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the visibility of the subreports based on the HasData property of each.

```
Private Sub Detail_Format(Cancel As Integer, FormatCount As Integer)
    If Me.Table_subreport.Report.HasData Then
        Me.Table_subreport.Visible = True
    Else
        Me.Table_subreport.Visible = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

the simplest way is :

```
Private Sub Detail_Format(Cancel As Integer, FormatCount As Integer)
    Me.Table_subreport.Visible = Me.Table_subreport.Report.HasData
End Sub
```